# Giving up ones life על קידוש ה׳ not to transgress גילוי עריות

Tags: history, talmud-bavli, arayot, talmud-yerushalmi

Are there any instances in *Shas (Bavli or Yerushalmi)* or even records of history where a group or even an individual gave up their life not to transgress גילוי עריות, Adultery?

Comment: I’m not clear on the site policy of Jews not Judaism as it applies to this question, so I’ve opened up a [question on Meta](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4625/9682) to discuss. To the OP or anyone else reading this, please feel free to leave your comments there.

Answer (score 15):

Probably the most famous story about a group that gave up their lives instead of doing Gilui Arayot is the story about 400 boys and girls that gave up their lives, as brought down in the Talmud [Gittin 57b:](https://www.sefaria.org/Gittin.57b.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en&p3=Psalms.68&lang3=bi)

> מעשה בד' מאות ילדים וילדות שנשבו לקלון הרגישו בעצמן למה הן מתבקשים אמרו אם אנו טובעין בים אנו באין לחיי העולם הבא דרש להן הגדול שבהן (תהלים סח, כג) אמר ה' מבשן אשיב אשיב ממצולות ים מבשן אשיב מבין שיני אריה אשיב ממצולות ים אלו שטובעין בים
>
> There was an incident involving four hundred boys and girls who were taken as captives for the purpose of prostitution. These children sensed on their own what they were expected to do, and they said: If we commit suicide and drown in the sea, will we come to eternal life in the World-to-Come? The oldest child among them expounded the verse: “The Lord said, I will bring back from Bashan, I will bring them back from the depths of the sea” (Psalms 68:23). “I will bring back from Bashan,” i.e., from between the teeth [bein shen] of the lion, and “I will bring them back from the depths of the sea” is referring to those who drown in the sea for the sake of Heaven.
>
> כיון ששמעו ילדות כך קפצו כולן ונפלו לתוך הים נשאו ילדים ק"ו בעצמן ואמרו מה הללו שדרכן לכך כך אנו שאין דרכנו לכך על אחת כמה וכמה אף הם קפצו לתוך הים ועליהם הכתוב אומר (תהלים מד, כג) כי עליך הורגנו כל היום נחשבנו כצאן טבחה
>
> When the girls heard this, they all leapt and fell into the sea. The boys then drew an a fortiori inference with regard to themselves and said: If these girls, for whom sexual intercourse with men is their natural way, act in such a manner, then we, for whom sexual intercourse with men is not our natural way, should all the more so conduct ourselves likewise. They too leapt into the sea. Concerning them and others like them the verse states: “As For Your sake we are killed all the day long; we are reckoned as sheep for the slaughter” (Psalms 44:23).